# JSFL delete Flash aso files

Tags: flash, ant, fdt, jsfl

I'm using FDT 3 and Ant to make a jsfl file that is then executed to compile fla's and I'm trying to figure out how to get the jsfl to remove the aso files. I've tried storing the path to the aso files in a property in Ant the is then added to the jsfl when its created and it works to remove the aso file but it means that everyone must edit that property to fit their machine, we are using Macs and Windows.

My question is, is there a way to have jsfl find and delete the aso files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answer rodrigoap but I was looking for a jsfl line of code that would point to the local users aso dir.

I actually found out the awsner.

```
FLfile.remove( fl.configURI + "/Classes/aso" );
```

fl.configURI points to the loacl users Flash Configuration Folder. Then you just tack on the rest of the path to the aso folder "/Classes/aso". The line above can be used to delete aso files from a jsfl file on a mac or on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about FDT, jsfl or aso. This Ant task will delete every .aso file in `./myPrj`:

```
 <delete>
    <fileset dir="./myPrj" includes="**/*.aso"/>
 </delete>
```